# Javascript parse DOM relationship string

Tags: javascript, string, dom

Is it possible to interpret a string DOM relationship path?  I would like to be able to pass in the relationship to a given node and for that to be processed within the function.  For example I have a function like this:

```
function doSomeStuff ( node, domPath ) {

  var targetNode = node.domPath;

}
```

And the call would be

```
doSomeStuff( myElement, "parentNode.previousSibling" )
```

The targetNode is unsurprisingly "undefined" - is it possible to parse the string in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `eval` but I don't recommend it because it can open the door to security holes and abuse.

Imagine a document like this:

```
<p>
  This is a <strong>test</strong>. With a <span>span</span>.
</p>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

This function takes a node as a starting point and resolves a "path", which consists of a series of field names separated by periods, against this node:

```
function resolvePath(node, path) {
    var start = path.split(".", 1)[0];
    var next = node[start];
    var remainder = path.slice(start.length + 1);
    if (remainder.length === 0)
        return next;
    return resolvePath(next, remainder);
}
```

With the document above, the `two` console.log calls show `true`:

```
var span = document.querySelector("span");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
console.log(resolvePath(span, "parentNode.nextElementSibling") === ul);
console.log(resolvePath(ul, "previousElementSibling.lastElementChild") === span);
```

This is a proof of concept. I've not taken care of things like extraneous spaces in the path. Also, it bombs if any step in the path, other than the last one, resolves to an undefined value. I find this desirable as it guards against typos in the path but there may be cases where bombing is not the desired behavior. Adapt as needed.

Comment: Thanks Louis - I should have mentioned I wanted to avoid Eval (although I had issues when trying it out anyway). Cheers :)